# how to provide some preset strings in text input in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

There's a text input in the form. User can input some text there, at same time, I want to provided some most used input texts as well - so User can chose one preset text in case it's same with what user want to input.

I tried collection: %w[balalal hahah], but this will disable user inputing their own text.

```
= f.input :Comment, wrapper: :prepend, label: false do
  %span.add-on
    Comment
    /%i.icon-comment
  = f.input_field :comment, placeholder: 'input your comment here', class: 'span2', size: 30
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Thanks for advise. There's a text input field, user can input some text, but I want to provide user with some texts which be inputed very often.

Comment: I guess you are talking about some sort of typeahead (autocompletion). For that you can use bootstraps typeahead or jquery's autocomplete. If I catch your drift.